# TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__api_user__.a.login(...) is undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

In my Vue.js project I have the following files:

`src/services/http.js`

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const HTTP = axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://localhost:3000/api/`,
  responseType: 'json'
})
```

`src/api/user.js`

```
import { HTTP } from '@/services/http'

export const user = {
  login (email, password) {
    HTTP.post('v1/login', { email: email, password: password })
  }
}
```

`src/store/user/actions.js`

```
import {user} from '@/api/user'

export const actions = {
  loginUser ({ commit }, params) {
    user.login(params.email, params.password)
  }
}
```

When I run my code it returns me following error:

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__api_user__.a.login(...) is undefined
```